# Matrix generalization of complex number identity

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

Consider a complex number $z = x + iy$ where $x, y\in \mathbb{R}$. Consider the case where
\begin{equation}
{\rm Im}\ z = c |z|^2
\iff
c = \frac{y}{|z|^2}
\end{equation}
where $c$ is some real constant. Observe that,

\begin{equation}
{\rm Im}\ z^{-1}
=
{\rm Im}\ \left\{\frac{1}{x + iy}\right\}
=
{\rm Im}\ \left\{\frac{x - iy}{x^2 + y^2}\right\}
=
-
\frac{y}{|z|^2}
=
-c
.
\end{equation}
I am curious to know if there is an extension of this into matrices. For example, if
\begin{equation}
{\rm Im}\ M
=
M\Sigma M{}^{*}
\end{equation}
then does
\begin{equation}
{\rm Im}\ M^{-1} 
\overset{?}{=}
-\Sigma.
\end{equation}
If so, what are the restrictions on $\Sigma$? (I suspect that $\Sigma$ will have to be diagonal and real, but I haven't been able to prove it.)

I've tried to prove this identity following a similar method as with the simple scalar case, i.e., multiply by the complex conjugate and its inverse, but all of my simplifications just lead back to the starting point.

Comment: What does the imaginary part of a matrix mean here?

Comment: If I have a matrix with complex elements, I can write it as $M = {\rm Re}\ M + i  {\rm Im}\ M$.